# Javascript: Decode String from File?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to decode a string from a file like this:

```
decode(fs.readFile(path.join(inbox.dir, inbox.messages[found].lastHash), 'utf8'))
```

But this is my output: `�w^~)�`

Comment: `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function that takes a callback. try `fs.readFileSync` or rewrite your code to use a callback.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick @nderscore